# Preprocessing each source file with a script using cmake

Tags: cmake, fortran

I'm attempting to add a cmake build system to an old fortran code that is littered with

```
!DEC$
```

style preprocessor commands. The old build system generated an awk script that converted these to the traditional C style preprocessor. The makefile would then just pipe the output directly to the compiler. I know with cmake that I can generate an intermediate file but I would like to avoid that if possible because I want to run this over every file.

Is there a method in cmake to pipe the output of a command directly to the compiler? Basically is there away to do the equivalent to

```
awk -f script.awk source.f | gfortran -x f95 -cpp -c -
```

in cmake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a cmake [add_custom_command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_command) to run awk and save the output to another file, in which case there will be no need for piping. To have piping, I think a bash script can be written which includes the piped statement. The script can then be defined as the cmake compiler ([Using a different compiler](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F)).